# Qt android - saved files disappearing

Tags: android, c++, qt

i'm working on a little app in Qt for android devices, and got stuck on something probably trivial: i want to write simple QVector into text files, with this code:

```
whereStuffIs = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
QString fileName = QString("test699.txt");
QDir::setCurrent(whereStuffIs);

QFile leFile;
leFile.setFileName(fileName);

leFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);

QTextStream out(&leFile);
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i){
    out << i << "\t" << someVector[i] << endl;
}
leFile.close();
```

and read it back again later (after  leaving the app). But when i quit and deploy the app again, the previos file is no longer there (at least according to this code:

```
QDir dir(whereStuffIs);
dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);
dir.setSorting(QDir::Name);

QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();

foreach(QFileInfo fi, list){
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(fi.fileName());
    ui->ListWidgetA->addItem(item);
}
```

It works like great within one rone of the app, file is created, and the FileList finds it, but after rerun, that's no longer the case. Altough it works just great when run on my windows machine. Please, what's missing?

Comment: Try it with `QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation`.

Comment: Thanks, it kind of works, but now files are written in publicly accessible location - '/mnt/sdcard', yet i was hoping to write at the more secure place like /data/data/org.nameAndSuch/files/